# Cross-Origin Request Blocked - firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, cors

i have some rest service deployed in my local machine(running on localhost). I am accessing those service using my angular js app. But when i deploy this in firefox i am getting cross origin request block exception but i am able to deploy same angular app on other browser IE and Chrome. Please help me out on this issue.

ErrorMessage:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/helloworld/rest/sayhi. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

$http( { url: 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/rest/sayhi/'+$scope.userquery, method: 'GET', dataType: 'json',
                transformResponse: function(data){
                   console.log("transformlog "+data);
                   return JSON.parse(data);
                },
                 headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
} }).then(function(data){console.log(data);} );

Where the spring mvc services are hosted in tomcat server. Both the server are browsers are in some machine.

Comment: And what exactly does the error message say?

Comment: And what is the URL of the page making the request? And is that different to what Chrome and IE say?

Comment: are you making an AJAX request to a different domain? what's the request URL?

Comment: @Warlock i am not making AJAX request. Please check updated question.

Comment: what happens if you enable CORS?

Comment: I am very new to this thing. can you please explain more where i need to enable the CORS, at my server side or client side. i have added following headers into my http request 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'

Answer (score 0):

http://patrickgrimard.com/2013/12/12/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-requests-with-spring-mvc/

I followed above link. I have added Cors headers in my spring-mvc-rest controller using filters and it worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think, actually it is problem on server side. You should enable CORS support on your spring application. It can be done by adding the filter

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.info("Adding CORS Headers ........................");        
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else { 
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }        
    }
}
```

I found it from the link [angularjs spring cross-origin request blocked](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/cross-origin-request-blocked-spring-mvc-restful-angularjs.html)